# excel : How to delete rows based on formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to delete all rows whose are based on a formula.
Indeed, I have a large Excel document which contains many rows and some of them are based on the value of other ones

Example :
 `Recipients`

```
   A |   B    |  C
   ------------------
   1 | salt   | bread
   2 | sugar  | ham
   3 | oil    | bread
   4 | salt   | bread
   5 | salt   | bread
   6 | sugar  | ham
   7 | oil    | butter
   8 | salt   | butter
   9 | salt   | butter
  10 | sugar  | ham
  11 | oil    | bread
  12 | oil    | ham
```

Some of the column doesn't contain the exact content but contain duplicate of the other rows.
In this example,  `ROW 5 CELL B`   contains an `=B4` formula.

Is there any way to delete all the rows that contains this kind of set up and do not repeat the human checking of each row ?

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: Please be more specific. What about cells that contain for example: `=If(X=A,A,B)`

Comment: I want to delete any of them, if once in the row it contains an <code> =to something else </code>. I don't really understand the way you describe your misunderstanding @Luuklag :/

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge on Excel, but where do you find Special ?

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for, thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways, how to find formulas:

1. As @pnuts has mentioned, you can do it via Home -> Find & Select option
2. via formula `=ISFORMULA()`
3. via VBA:

   ```
   Sub Find_formula()
   For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   If col.HasFormula() = True Then
          col.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
   End If

   Next col
   End Sub
   ```

Just realized, that you wanted to remove the rows. Just replace this part `col.Interior.ColorIndex = 30` to this `col.EntireRow.Delete`